# Disable browser's autocomplete credentials in input type password in ZKoss

Tags: input, textbox, passwords, zk, zk-grid

I would ask you a question...
I want to disable browser's autocomplete credentials in input type password in ZKoss.

My ZK version is 6.5

Here is my zul code

```
<grid width="344px">
    <rows>
      <row>
        <label value="Username" />
        <textbox id="username" name="j_username" focus="true" hflex="true" />
      </row>
      <row>
        <label value="Password" />
        <textbox id="password" type="password" name="j_password" hflex="true" />
      </row>
    </rows>
</grid>
```

Do you have any ideas? solutions? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<zk xmlns:ca="client/attribute">
    <grid>
        <!-- removed for brevity -->
        <textbox ca:autocomplete="off" />
    </grid>
</zk>
```